# What is the result of a 180 degree rotation of a cube around the line joining the midpoints of opposite edges?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

This is supposed to be an isomorphism, but I can't visualize it.  Suppose that there is a 180 degree rotation around the line joining the midpoint of the left edge of the top face to the midpoint of the right edge of the bottom face.  Where do the top and bottom faces end up?

Answer (score 1):

Top face ends up left, bottom face ends up right. As I convinced myself by picking up the nearest cube lying around (a Rubik's cube), holding it at those midpoints, and doing the rotation. The top and left faces swap places, as do back and front, and bottom and right.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use a Rubik's cube to verify.  What really helped was to hold the cube so that the rotation axis is perpendicular to the floor.. That reinforces the idea that the axis does not move and the line between the front and left faces swings around and ends up on top of itself in the reverse direction. The same thing happens between the bottom and right faces. The back and front faces swap places.  I can see it but it still seems kind of amazing..